# How input works in C

Tags: c, input, scanf

I'm quite confused about the function `scanf` and how the input works in C.

See this code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE pt = *stdin;
    char b[100];
    scanf("%s", b);
    scanf("%s", b); //breakpoint here
    scanf(" ");     //breakpoint here
}
```

When the code runs, I input `12345` into the console. I found that `pt _ptr`(which I don't actually know what it is) has the value `"12345\n\n"` and `b[]` has the value `"12345"`.

Then I continue the program and input `23456`. Now `pt _ptr` is `"23456\n\n"` and `b[]` is `"23456"`.

My question :

- How does the input work in C? Why does `pt _ptr` have the value of `"12345\n\n"` not `"12345\n"` since I pressed enter only one time(and it seems like the function `scanf` skips those two `\n` after successfully read `"12345"` ).

Comment: Did you read documentation of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) and of every other function you are using?

Comment: How scanf works will vary from operating system to operating system. For example [here's how it works on a Mac](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/libkern/stdio/scanf.c), chosen just by virtue of being the easiest version to find.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking under the carpet... You are not supposed to copy `FILE` structs so the first line

```
FILE pt = *stdin;
```

results are actually undefined. Do not look inside, unless you are willing to read and understand the source of you standard C library!

The rest of the code is pretty easy to understand, as `b` has always the expected value, isn't it?

Comment: You might even have some C implementations which won't compile that assignment (e.g. because `FILE` would be `typedef`-ed to some *private* `struct`).

Comment: YEP! But I thought that was how I should do it if I want to know the data in stdin, I mean, how to actually look at the current stdin?

Comment: @SantiSantichaivekin: You do not _look into_ stdin. You _read from_ stdin. And you _write to_ stdout, BTW. `FILE` does not have any public field, so you can use it only through the library functions.

Comment: If you just want to see what characters are coming next in stdin without reading them, [someone has a StackOverflow question about that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993742/is-there-anyway-to-peek-at-the-stdin-buffer)

Comment: @Dan: Yes, but IME, peeking that way is not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

It is not apparent what it is you are really trying to do besides learn scanf, but you are also invoking ***[stdin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3x292kth.aspx)*** and the `FILE` struct.

***Using*** ***[fscanf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa246414%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)*** instead, (read link for details on `fscanf) it will be easier to use all three.

Here is a simple example of how you can combine *fscanf, FILE*, and *stdin*:

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp={0};
    int res =0 //use to check return value of fscanf 
    char buf[80]; //use 80 for demonstration only
    fp = fopen("c:\\dev\\play\\playtext.txt", "w");//create file and stream
    res = fscanf(stdin, "%s", buf);//stream input from stdin
    if(res == EOF) 
    {
        printf("Exiting...  input error");//notify and exit upon error
        return -1;
    }
    while (strstr(buf, "quit") == NULL)//allow exit by typing quit
    {
        if(fputs(buf, fp) == EOF) return -1;
        buf[0]=0;//reset buffer
        res = fscanf(stdin, "%s", buf);
        if(res == EOF) 
        {
            printf("Exiting...  input error");//notify and exit upon error
            return -1;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the function fscanf() returns the number of parameters set, never EOF, though it can return 0 if no parameters are set.

Comment: @user3629249 -  It may be you are using an old implementation compiler?.  From my documentation - fscanf _Reads input from the specified stream and converts it into a series of values according to the specifications of the formatting string. If an input failure occurs before any conversion, the function returns EOF (-1); otherwise, the function returns the number of input items successfully read._  From ***[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa246414%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)***, From Linux ***[man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf)***. (look under ***Return Value***)