# how can I force scanf to take the \n character as input?

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to take string input in an infinite `while` loop that saves the string in the same array every time, but I wish this loop to terminate when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The code looks something like this:

```
int main()
{
    char input[1000];
    while (1)
    {
        scanf("%s",input);
        if (input[0] == '\n'){ break; } //the problem is that scanf never gets the \n
        else{...}
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A newline, `\n`, is considered a white-space character.

If you read the `C11` spec, chapter §7.21.6.2 you can see, regarding the `%s` format specifier with `scanf()` family

> `s`
>
> Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters.

So, using a `scanf()` call with `%s`, you cannot intake a (only) `\n`, which is indeed a white-space charterer.

You need to use [`getc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getc) to read a newline.

Alternatively, you can use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) which *actually* reads and stores the trailing newline.

FWIW, `int main()` should better be `int main(void)`, at least.

Comment: Any reason for the _wholesale_ downvote, dear downvoter?

Comment: is there a way to see what is the first character in the buffer without getting it out of there?

Comment: @xixhxix: That's a separate question, and I'll bet you can find one already. But the answer is `getc` followed by `ungetc`. See `man getc`. (To save you the trouble of searching *this time*, here's the already-asked question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13993742/1566221)

Answer (score 2):

Edit:
You can tell `scanf()` to accept specific char with `scanf("%[a-zA-Z0-9 ]", ...);`

Comment: Was not sure. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome, take a look to [Escape sequences in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences)

Comment: The `s` after the `[]` is wrong, which is unfortunate, since this *should* really be the best answer.

Comment: @EOF i need it to accept all normal string characters and the new line character, how can i accomplish that

Comment: @xixhxix: Provided you're on a POSIX system with ASCII charset, `%[!-~\n]` will accept all non-whitespace characters and newline.

Comment: @xixhxix If code is to "accept all normal string characters and the new line character", when should it _stop_ accepting characters?

Answer (score 2):

The conversion `"%c"` matches any character including whitespace. If you really need to use `scanf()`, use it with that.

```
// you can put this in a loop
char ch;
if (scanf("%c", &ch) != 1) /* error */;
printf("the character read is '%c' and has value %d\n", ch, ch);
```

Note that solutions using other functions (`getc()`, `fgets()`) are way better.

Comment: The OP still requires to read the string when the input is not only a `/n`, maybe `scanf("%20[^\n]%c", buff, &c);` would solve it by storing the `/n` in `c`

Comment: @PeCosta `scanf("%20[^\n]%c", buff, &c);` does not work when the first `char` is `'\n'`.  This seems to be a case OP is looking for with code `if (input[0] == '\n')`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, use `fgets()` to read the line and `strcspn()` to lop off the potential trailing `'\n'`

```
int main(void) {
  char input[1000];
  while (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)) {
    input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0';
    if (input[0] == '\0') { 
      break;
    } else { 
      ; // ...
    }
  }
return 0;
}
```

or don't lop off the `'\n'` [@R Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33739991/2410359)

```
int main(void) {
  char input[1000];
  while (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)) {
    if (input[0] == '\n') { 
      break;
    } else { 
      ; // ...
    }
  }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgets(input, 1000, stdin)` instead.

Then use `size_t s = strlen(input);` and, if the returned length is adequate, look at `input[s - 1]` which will be the  newline character, which you can test with `input[s - 1] == '\n'`.

Comment: In uncommon cases, `size_t s = strlen(input); input[s - 1]` leads to UB when a `'\0'` was the first `char` read.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `scanf`, using `fgets`.

```
while (1)
{
    if ( fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) == NULL )
    {
       // Error reading. Perhaps EOF is reached.
       break; //???
    }

    if (input[0] == '\n'){ break; }
    else{...}
}
```